# How to sort out pairs of columns horizontally based on a shared prefix?

Tags: pandas

My input is a dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'node1': ['abc-1', 'xyz-1', 'abc-1', 'xyz-2', 'xyz-2', 'ghi-2'],
 'p1': [1, 10, 3, 1, 2, 6],
 'p2': [9, 2, 11, 4, 5, 3],
 'node2': ['xyz-1', 'abc-1', 'xyz-1', 'def-2', 'def-2', 'xyz-1']})

print(df)

   node1  p1  p2  node2
0  abc-1   1   9  xyz-1
1  xyz-1  10   2  abc-1
2  abc-1   3  11  xyz-1
3  xyz-2   1   4  def-2
4  xyz-2   2   5  def-2
5  ghi-2   6   3  xyz-1
```

I'm trying to sort the nodes so the ones with the same prefix go in the same side and thus the same column. But we need also to do the same with points `p1` and `p2`. For example row index `1`, the nodes `xyz-1` and `abc-1` will be reversed and we should do this at the same time with the points. So this row becomes : `1 | abc-1 | 2 | 10 | xyz-1`.

I was able to sort the nodes but really ignore how to do the same with the points.

```
final = df[['node1', 'node2']].apply(np.sort, axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
final.columns = ['node1', 'node2']

print(final)

   node1  node2
0  abc-1  xyz-1
1  abc-1  xyz-1
2  abc-1  xyz-1
3  def-2  xyz-2
4  def-2  xyz-2
5  ghi-2  xyz-1
```

My expected output is the one below. It is one of the two possible outputs because the side is not important. For example, the second accepted output will be a dataframe where the `abc`, `def` and `ghi` nodes are in the right side (`column 2`).

```
   node1  p1  p2  node2
0  abc-1   1   9  xyz-1
1  abc-1   2  10  xyz-1
2  abc-1   3  11  xyz-1
3  def-2   4   1  xyz-2
4  def-2   5   2  xyz-2
5  ghi-2   6   3  xyz-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask:

```
m = final.eq(df[['node1', 'node2']]).all(axis=1)
final[['p1', 'p2']] = df[['p1', 'p2']].where(m, other=df[['p2', 'p1']].values)
final = final[df.columns]
```

Output:

```
>>> final
   node1  p1  p2  node2
0  abc-1   1   9  xyz-1
1  abc-1   2  10  xyz-1
2  abc-1   3  11  xyz-1
3  def-2   4   1  xyz-2
4  def-2   5   2  xyz-2
5  ghi-2   6   3  xyz-1
```